# Memory efficient mean pairwise distance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-spatial

I am aware of the [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) function and how to compute the mean from the resulting matrix/ndarray.

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(10000, 2)
>>> y = pdist(x, metric='euclidean')
>>> y.mean()
0.5214255824176626
```

In the example above `y` gets quite large (nearly 2,500 times as large as the input array):

```
>>> y.shape
(49995000,)
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> getsizeof(x)
160112
>>> getsizeof(y)
399960096
>>> getsizeof(y) / getsizeof(x)
2498.0019986009793
```

But since I am only interested in the mean pairwise distance, the distance matrix doesn't have to be kept in memory. Instead the mean of each row (or column) can be computed seperatly. The final mean value can then be computed from the row mean values.

Is there already a function which exploit this property or is there an easy way to extend/combine existing functions to do so?

Comment: Can you add an example to clarify?

Comment: @Mstaino I edited the question. I hope it is now clear.

Comment: Would the metric `sqeuclidean` instead of `euclidean` be okay?

Comment: @Divakar `sqeuclidean` works as well, but how can this reduce the memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the square version of distance, it is equivalent to using the variance with n-1:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10000, 2)
y = np.array([[1,1], [0,0], [2,0]])
print(pdist(x, 'sqeuclidean').mean())
print(np.var(x, 0, ddof=1).sum()*2)
>>0.331474285845873
0.33147428584587346
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to weight each row by the number of observations that make up the mean. For example the pdist of a 3 x 2 matrix is the flattened upper triangle (offset of 1) of the squareform 3 x 3 distance matrix.

```
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
arr
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
pdist(arr)
array([2.82842712, 5.65685425, 2.82842712])
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
square = pairwise_distances(arr)
square
array([[0.        , 2.82842712, 5.65685425],
       [2.82842712, 0.        , 2.82842712],
       [5.65685425, 2.82842712, 0.        ]])
square[triu_indices(square.shape[0], 1)]
array([2.82842712, 5.65685425, 2.82842712])
```

There is the [`pairwise_distances_chuncked`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked.html) function that can be used to iterate over the distance matrix row by row, but you will need to keep track of the row index to make sure you only take the mean of values in the upper/lower triangle of the matrix (distance matrix is symmetrical). This isn't complicated, but I imagine you will introduce a significant slowdown.

```
tot = ((arr.shape[0]**2) - arr.shape[0]) / 2
weighted_means = 0
for i in gen:
    if r < arr.shape[0]:
        sm = i[0, r:].mean()
        wgt = (i.shape[1] - r) / tot
        weighted_means += sm * wgt
       r += 1
```